# Webpack Mix styles (SCSS and LESS) generates into a javascript-like file

Tags: laravel, webpack, sass, less, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel's webpack mix to compile my assets including my styles using scss and less, how ever, the compiled file of my styles is not what I've expected. This is my webpack mix code...

```
mix
  .react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js')
  .react('resources/js/signup.js', 'public/assets/js')
  .sass('resources/scss/styles.scss', 'public/assets/css')
  .extract();
```

but when I check the compiled `styles.scss`, the content looks like

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports["default"] = void 0;

var _react = _interopRequireWildcard(__webpack_require__(/*! react */ "./node_modules/react/index.js"));

var _colorAdmin = __webpack_require__(/*! ../../../components/_color-admin */ "./resources/js/components/_color-admin/_color-admin.js");

function _getRequireWildcardCache() { if (typeof WeakMap !== "function") return null; var cache = new WeakMap(); _getRequireWildcardCache = function _getRequireWildcardCache() { return cache; }; return cache; }

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__

...
```

Comment: your styles.scss should have scss code and then compile your style again, then it will work.

Comment: my scss files have scss content in them, I ran the compiler again but still, a js-like code. My workaround was to use Koala.

Comment: did you try to move your second line to other MIX like this `mix.react('resources/js/signup.js', 'public/assets/js');` and also try with out `.extract()`